# Java how to extend a 3rd party application while keeping compatibility

Tags: java, open-source, extend

I'm developing an application based on a open source project. We paid the developers to make our own application, closed source, based on their code. We do want to stay compatible with the original package, security and feature updates will be merged with our application.

Of course, the biggest problem here is the merging with new updates if I heavily modified the original code. I searched the web for the best solution and among others I found websites like [this one](https://www.perforce.com/blog/vcs/how-extend-open-source-projects). So i decided not to modify the original code as much as I could. If I want to add functionality to a existing feature, I extend the original class, make the application point to my extended class (which is a small enough modification not to be a problem), and implement my changes.

The problem here is with properties in the 3rd party class that are of a type I also want to extend. In below example `class A` does some modifications on the property `myClass` that I want it to keep doing. But `class B`, which extends `class A`, contains a property with a type that extends `MyClass` itself, here `MyCustomClass`. Inside `class B` I want the property `myCustomClass` to be a extension of `myClass`, any changes made to `myClass` should be accessible in `myCustomClass`.

As far as I know, casting `myClass` to `myCustomClass` isn't possible as `myClass` simply is not of type `myCustomClass`. 
So what is the best solution here that keeps compatibility with `class A` and does not involve just copying all the code from `class A` as that would create the exact same problems if `class A` gets an update?

Here some example code that should explain my question better:

```
// Classes 'A' and 'MyClass' are 3rd party, I do not want to edit them
public class A {
    private MyClass myClass;

    A(){
        myClass = new MyClass();

        // Changes I want to keep doing
        doSomething();
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        // Do some calculations to myClass and modify it accordingly 
    }

    public MyClass getMyClass(){
        return myClass
    }
}


// Classes 'B' and 'MyCustomClass' are 1st party, I can do anything I want with them :)
public class B extends A{
    private MyCustomClass myCustomClass;        

    B(){
        super();

        myCustomClass = ?????????;


        // Extremely important message, this should keep working
        System.out.println(myCustomClass.verySpecialString);

        // Build further on made modifications, this should keep working too
        useModificationsByClassA();
    }

    public void useModificationsByClassA(){
        // Use result of class A's calculations in order to continue
    }
}


public class MyCustomClass extends MyClass{
    private String verySpecialString;

    MyCustomClass(){
        super();

        verySpecialString = "Hey!";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe your wish is possible.  The moment you extend the code base it becomes your responsibility to maintain the changes.  The only way to keep the two in synch is to commit your changes to the original project as open source.  That way future releases have your changes as well.  This means the original code providers will have to agree to merge your stuff in.

Comment: @duffymo, my project diverges from the original code by quite a lot. That won't work. If this isn't possible, what is the closest possible solution? Or is the only thing I can do just copy `class A`'s code?

Comment: Copy code?  Goodness, no.  You can use the library as a dependency and write your own extensions.  You acknowledge and accept the risk that if the library makes changes you'll either have to upgrade to stay in synch or remain behind on the older version.  You should treat the library as inviolate - do not alter it in any way.  Extend, wrap, use composition, but don't extend by editing their source files.

Comment: Yeah I know I will have to do some work to keep updated. That's fine. A specific problem i was trying to solve here is changing the layout of some buttons, preferably without editing the original code. How would i do that in a extension?

Comment: Swing UI?  Oh, boy.  Now you've got a problem, because I doubt that the authors gave much thought to extension points and making it easy for you to do such a thing.  You can write your own JPanel, give it the buttons you'd like to have, and configure them with Listeners that make calls into the library that you want them to have.  But that code is all yours.  You would only use their API to add calls into the button listeners to perform desired tasks.

Comment: You paid them to make these extensions.  Maybe you would have been better off figuring out how you might want to alter their stuff and make the design and implementation of those extension points part of the new implementation.  The authors won't mind having you come back and pay for every new extension.  They would prefer that you have to pay.  It's up to you to think through the requirements.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. Gives me some insight into possible solutions. Guess this is gonna be some work for me :)

Comment: Ask them what their API is.  It should be completely separate from any UI.  You should be able to wrap it as a REST service and call it from a web or mobile UI if you wish.  I think it's a poor design to tie yourself to UI.  UI technologies come and go, but a DSL to solve a problem and a public API keeps your stuff relevant for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

In a general way, in an application, library, and so for... some components are designed to be extended (because though for) and some other components are really not designed to be extended.
But modified an existing component is generally not the way to extend the application behavior.
Because exsiting components are generally not designed to be modified. Their actual logic/processing may strongly change from a version to another. These may be removed from the source code or anything else....
So you will have a hard time to merge the updates of the original source into the source code of the modified implementation of the application.

Long story short : an application *may* allow to be extended but in this case it also provides the extension points, you cannot change any class in any way.
If you want to extend some parts of the original source code **you have to know whether the actual application is designed to be extended and if yes how**.
If it is not designed to be extended, **you should accept that the application updates may not be integrated (or be hard to integrate) into the modified application.**

Comment: Ok, but if it just isn't made to be extended, is there any way to reliably add changes? Or am I just out of luck? What is a common way to address a problem like this?

Comment: reliably ? Never as potentially you may need to change many classes/files. You could even need to change the test classes (if these have). There is not really many solutions : forking the application as an internal may be fine in the first times but it may also be a risky bet later.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the adapter or decorator pattern, and use composition instead of inheritance.  For example:

```
public class B {
    private final A a;        
    private final MyCustomClass myCustomClass;

    B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
        myCustomerClass = new MyCustomClass(a.getMyClass());
    }

   public void doSomething()  {
     a.doSomething();   // updates the state of a.myClass.
     myCustomerClass.doSomething();  // use the change of a.myClass to do more stuff         
   }
}

public class MyCustomClass {
   private final MyClass myClass;
   private String verySpecialString;

   public MyCustomClass(MyClass myClass) {
      this.myClass = myClass;
   }

   public void doSomething() {
      verySpecialString = "Hey!" + myClass.getSomeResult();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought about this solution before and tried it, but didn't really like it as it broke a lot of things. But i guess I do not have a lot of choice, gonna invest some more to try and make this work. Will select the answer if this is what I end up doing :)

Comment: @Andrew S The OP needs to change existing classes to make the change effective. So in the facts, the composition will be long to implement without really protecting you because if you modify an existing class by another class (that is the compositor class), all references to the existing classes you changed have to be changed and watched for modifications.